# Grab ID from row to verify update

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I'm trying to update rows of a table that is a 1:N relationship from the main Customer table, so because it can have many rows per ID I needed to add a unique ID 'contact_id'

Now when I try to update the row with:

`cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE ContactInfo SET f_name = @val1, l_name = @val2, email = @val3, phone = @val4, title = @val5, notes = @val6 WHERE customer_id = @cid and where contact_id = @contID";`

I get an error saying Object reference not set to instance of object.

All of my parameters are working except for the one that I set for contact_id, which I am trying to pull from a TextBox contID

Here is my parameter:

```
TextBox contID = (TextBox)gvr.FindControl("tb_0");
```

Here is my actual parameter:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@contID", contID.Text);
```

And here is my templatefield:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Contact ID">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lb_0" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("contact_id") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="tb_0" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("contact_id") %>' Enabled="false"></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

Any ideas why this is not working?

Edit: I have an edititemtemplate in there because I tried pulling the parameter from the textbox as well as the label (neither worked), it is not an editable field.

Comment: are you using a foreach loop? Show the button click or wherever it is you're trying to update.

Comment: there's no reason to use a foreach

Comment: There is a reason, you can update multiple rows at once with a for each, and it's easy to find the control... foreach(GridViewRow gvr in GridView1.Rows) and using the 'TextBox contID' line you have will work to find that control.

Comment: I don't want to update multiple rows at the same time, I want to be able to update one contact of a Customer ID at a time. So if I search customer ID '23' and it comes back with Contact IDs '1','2','3', then I want to be able to click 'edit' in my gridview and have it only update where contact_id = '2'.

Comment: I think I know what you mean now.. do you mean because there is going to be multiple tb_0s? I've never used a foreach before though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be able to do it for you if you don't want to use a foreach...

```
GridViewRow gvr = (GridViewRow)(sender as Control).Parent.Parent;
TextBox contID = (TextBox)gvr.FindControl("tb_0");
```

I use the above within button clicks and within SelectedIndexChanged.

If a single record is always going to show in the gridview, you can use a foreach as well..like this..

```
 foreach (GridViewRow gvr in gvGridView1.Rows)
 {
    TextBox contID = (TextBox)gvr.FindControl("tb_0");
 }
```

I have to use this foreach because my company wanted an 'Excel' like update for their gridview.

Comment: Thanks.. but for some reason I was getting an error in the wrong spot, I actually labeled one of my id's wrong and that was where the problem was

Comment: Easy enough. Glad you got it figured out.